# ASP.Net MVC 3 application automated installer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanted to know if it's possible to automate the deployment of an ASP.Net MVC application.  This application is meant to run locally on the host PC and I what I want to do is create an installer to make it easy for end-users to setup quickly.  I've never tried this approach for web applications and I wanted to see what my options are.

I was thinking of using something like [Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/) or [aspNETserve](http://code.google.com/p/aspnetserve/) and somehow automating the installer to set everything up on the fly.  Any insight is appreciated, if there are any questions or if more details are required, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: So you want the end-user to be running the website locally on their machine? That seems to defeat the purpose of making it a web application.

Comment: @Tejs Couldn't it be a server app on LAN?

Comment: @David what? If he's trying to make a "server" app, then it seems like making a client service would be far superior.

Comment: @Tejs Of course service would be better, but hasn't OP already said it's a web app?

Comment: Yes, but it sounds like what he's trying to do is a *bad idea*(tm), and thus just suggesting an answer may be doing him a disservice.

Comment: @Tejs and David, I realize this may seems backwards, unfortunately this is a requirement for the project, this MVC application is essentially just using the browser as an interface in order to be consistent with the look, feel and operation of my clients other server-hosted web applications.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the WebPlatform installer to set all your dependencies setup. You can script that tool and have it run all the pre-reqs for you. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433092.aspx)

Also, I would use IIS Express to host. It is also setup via script to setup your app root, paths, permissions, etc. (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/)

So in theory a simple script or installer could deploy all of this for you and run the above two as well as deploying your application.